# Sumar o restar valores de input dinámico con Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Antes de empezar a publicar quiero recalcar que no soy experta en javascript, recién lo estoy conociendo.

Estuve tratando de sumar o restar los elementos dinámicos de mi formulario. 
El problema es que no puedo realizar la suma dinámica o restar si una fila es borrada o agregada.

Código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Refresca Producto: Refresco la Lista de Productos dentro de la Tabla
        // Si es vacia deshabilito el boton guardar para obligar a seleccionar al menos un producto al usuario
        // Sino habilito el boton Guardar para que pueda Guardar
        function RefrescaProducto() {
            var ip = [];
            var i = 0;
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //Deshabilito el Boton Guardar
            $('.iProduct').each(function(index, element) {
                i++;
                ip.push({
                    id_pro: $(this).val()
                });
            });
            // Si la lista de Productos no es vacia Habilito el Boton Guardar
            if (i > 0) {
                $('#guardar').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            var ipt = JSON.stringify(ip); //Convierto la Lista de Productos a un JSON para procesarlo en tu controlador
            $('#ListaPro').val(encodeURIComponent(ipt));
        }

        function agregarProducto() {

            var sel = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').val(); //Capturo el Value del Producto
            var text = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').text(); //Capturo el Nombre del Producto- Texto dentro del Select


            var sptext = text.split();

            var newtr = '<tr class="item"  data-id="' + sel + '">';
            newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct" >' + sel + '</td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td> <input  class="form-control" id="1" name="precio" value="0" required /></td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><input  class="form-control" id="2" name="cantidad" value="0" required /></td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><input  class="form-control"  id="3" name="total" value="0" required /></td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-item"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr>';

            $('#ProSelected').append(newtr); //Agrego el Producto al tbody de la Tabla con el id=ProSelected

            RefrescaProducto(); //Refresco Productos

            $('.remove-item').off().click(function(e) {
                $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); //En accion elimino el Producto de la Tabla
                if ($('#ProSelected tr.item').length == 0)
                    $('#ProSelected .no-item').slideDown(300);
                RefrescaProducto();
            });
            $('.iProduct').off().change(function(e) {
                RefrescaProducto();
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <from>
            <h2>Comprar productos</h2>
            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Agregar</button>
            <input type="hidden" id="ListaPro" name="ListaPro" value="" required />
            <table id="TablaPro" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Producto</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Acción</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="ProSelected">
                    <!--Ingreso un id al tbody-->
                    <tr>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><span id="total">0</span> <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="total_final" name="total_final"  value="0" readonly /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            <!--Agregue un boton en caso de desear enviar los productos para ser procesados-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" id="guardar" name="guardar" class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-right">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </from>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">

            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar producto a la lista</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Producto</label>
                            <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="pro_id" name="pro_id" data-width='100%'>
                                        <option value="Lentes">Lentes</option>
                                        <option value="Casco">Casco</option>
                                        <option value="Gorra">Gorra</option>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <!--Uso la funcion onclick para llamar a la funcion en javascript-->
                        <button type="button" onclick="agregarProducto()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Agregar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No tengo muy claro lo que quieres hacer, pero podrias probar la función onChange en el input o inputs que cambian para que cuando cambien tomen los nuevos valores y lanzar una función que haga nuevamente la suma o resta.

Comment: lo que quieres hacer es cuando ya tienes agregado el producto que te de el total al tener la cantidad y el precio o de que manera

Comment: Si exactamente eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu procedimiento está correcto, pero si quieres tener en cuenta cuando el usuario actualice la cantidad o el precio , puedes debes tomar en Sub Total antes de la modificación para luego restarle al resultado final , y para eliminar basta con obtener el valor del Sub total a eliminar para restar.

```js
function RefrescaProducto() {
            var ip = [];
            var i = 0;
            $('#guardar').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //Deshabilito el Boton Guardar
            $('.iProduct').each(function(index, element) {
                i++;
                ip.push({
                    id_pro: $(this).val()
                });
            });
            // Si la lista de Productos no es vacia Habilito el Boton Guardar
            if (i > 0) {
                $('#guardar').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            var ipt = JSON.stringify(ip); //Convierto la Lista de Productos a un JSON para procesarlo en tu controlador
            $('#ListaPro').val(encodeURIComponent(ipt));
        }

        function agregarProducto() {

            var sel = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').val(); //Capturo el Value del Producto
            var text = $('#pro_id').find(':selected').text(); //Capturo el Nombre del Producto- Texto dentro del Select


            var sptext = text.split();

            var newtr = '<tr class="item"  data-id="'+sel+'">';
            newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct" >' + sel + '</td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="cantidad[]" name="lista[]" onChange="Calcular(this);" value="1" /></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="precunit[]" name="lista[]" onChange="Calcular(this);" value="0"/></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" id="totalitem[]" name="lista[]" readonly /></td>';
            newtr = newtr + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-item" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr>';

            $('#ProSelected').append(newtr); //Agrego el Producto al tbody de la Tabla con el id=ProSelected

            RefrescaProducto(); //Refresco Productos

            $('.remove-item').off().click(function(e) {
                var total = document.getElementById("total");
                total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML) - parseFloat(this.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3].childNodes[0].value);
                $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); //En accion elimino el Producto de la Tabla
                if ($('#ProSelected tr.item').length == 0)
                    $('#ProSelected .no-item').slideDown(300);
                RefrescaProducto();
                
                Calcular(e.target);
            });
            $('.iProduct').off().change(function(e) {
                RefrescaProducto();
            
            });
        }

        
        function Calcular(ele) {
            var cantidad = 0, precunit = 0, totalitem = 0 ;
            var tr = ele.parentNode.parentNode;
            var nodes = tr.childNodes;
        
            for (var x = 0; x<nodes.length;x++) {
                
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == 'cantidad[]') {
                    cantidad = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
                }
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == 'precunit[]') {
                    precunit = parseFloat(nodes[x].firstChild.value,10);
                }
                if (nodes[x].firstChild.id == 'totalitem[]') {
                    anterior = nodes[x].firstChild.value;
                    totalitem = parseFloat((precunit*cantidad),10);
                    nodes[x].firstChild.value = totalitem;
                }
            }
            // Resultado final de cada fila ERROR, al editar o eliminar una fila
            var total = document.getElementById("total");
            if (total.innerHTML == 'NaN') {
                total.innerHTML = 0;
                // 
            }
            total.innerHTML = parseFloat(total.innerHTML)+totalitem -anterior ;    
        }
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <div class="container">
        <from>
            <h2>Comprar productos</h2>
            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Agregar</button>
            <input type="hidden" id="ListaPro" name="ListaPro" value="" required />
            <table id="TablaPro" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Producto</th>
                        <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Acción</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="ProSelected">
                    <!--Ingreso un id al tbody-->
                    <tr>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><span id="total">0</span> <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="total_final" name="total_final"  value="0" readonly /></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            <!--Agregue un boton en caso de desear enviar los productos para ser procesados-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" id="guardar" name="guardar" class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-right">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </from>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">

            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar producto a la lista</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Producto</label>
                            <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="pro_id" name="pro_id" data-width='100%'>
                                        <option value="Lentes">Lentes</option>
                                        <option value="Casco">Casco</option>
                                        <option value="Gorra">Gorra</option>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <!--Uso la funcion onclick para llamar a la funcion en javascript-->
                        <button type="button" onclick="agregarProducto()" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Agregar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Gracias @Dev.Joel, una pregunta como harías en el modal ya no un select si no una table para seleccionar muchos productos y que al darle aceptar esta se muestre en la pagina principal??

Answer (score 0):

espero esto te funcione.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#total").focusout(function (e) {
    var cantidad = $("#1").val();
    var precio = $("#2").val();
    var total = parseFloat(cantidad) * parseFloat(precio);
    $("#3").val(total);
  });
});
```

de esta manera obtienes lo que pongas en los input que tienes en la tabla

```
var newtr = '<tr class="item"  data-id="' + sel + '">';
    newtr = newtr + '<td class="iProduct" >' + sel + '</td>';
    newtr = newtr + '<td><form id="total"> <input class="form-control" id="1" name="precio" value="0" required /></td>';
    newtr = newtr + '<td><input  class="form-control" id="2" name="cantidad" value="0" required /></td>';
    newtr = newtr + '<td><input  class="form-control" id="3" name="total" value="0" required /> </form></td>';
    newtr = newtr + '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove-item"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr>';
```

encierras dentro de un formulario tus inputs para realizar la función espero te ayude.

Comment: json lo implementé y no funciona :(, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: estuve haciendo pruebas encierra pon el formulario con los input en un solo td de la tabla

Comment: Te cuento que encontré una forma de hacerlo logra sumarlas pero tengo unos pequeños problemas al momento de editar o eliminar una fila.  Mira: https://codepen.io/Jhoss/pen/oZaEpR

Answer (score 0):

Bueno aquí hice un ejemplo y te lo dejo para lo apliques a tu proyecto, lo que se debe hacer es jugar un poco con los eventos que tiene **JQuery** que facilitan el trabajo, en este caso use el evento **keyup**, lo cual indica que cada que se levante una tecla luego de que la presiones ocurrirá algo que tu desees.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  function multiplicar(){
    
    var uno, dos, tres, operacion;
  
      uno = $('#uno');
      dos = $('#dos');
      tres = $('#tres');
      
      operacion = parseInt(uno.val()) * parseInt(dos.val());
      tres.val(operacion);
    
  }
  
  $("#uno").keyup(function(){
      
      var dos;
      dos = $('#dos').val();
      
      if(dos != ""){
        multiplicar()
      }
      
  });
  
  $("#dos").keyup(function(){
      
      var uno;
      uno = $('#uno').val();
      
      if(dos != ""){
        multiplicar()
      }
      
  });
  
 
})
```

```css
#lista{
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
    
      <h1>Operaciones</h1>
    
      <ul id=lista>
        <li><input type = text name=valor1 id=uno></li>
        <li><input type = text name=valor2 id=dos></li>
        <li><input type = text name=valor3 id=tres></li>
      </ul>
      
      
  </body>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, te cuento que hice anteriormente algo similar, lo que pasa es que como este formulario es dinámico pueden haber muchas filas. Y es ese el problema que tengo.

Comment: Y por que no tratas de hacer este procedimiento antes de agregar el producto a la lista de detalles de los productos, si me logras entender?