# script restar numeros separados por comas

Tags: javascript, html, script, input

Buenas tardes comunidad espero me puedan ayudar
saco la hora de entrada y de salida  eso se me genera bien al darme las horas trabajadas me las da separadas las horas y minutos con una coma

me genera de manera correcta las horas trabajas pero al restar las horas que debe trabajar no me manda los decimales.
horas laboradas que son 13,40 le resto horas debe trabajar  me da diferecia de 3 horas y debería decir 3,40

```
    <input type="time" id="inicio" value="12:40">
<input type="time" id="final" value="06:45">
<input id="resultado">

<input type="text" id="resultadon" ">
<input type="text" id="finaln" >

<input id="resultadon">


<script>  
 const inicio = document.getElementById('inicio'),
    final = document.getElementById('final'),
    resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

function horaFija(hora) {
    const dia = new Date()
    dia.setHours(...hora.split(':'), 0)
    return dia
}

function calculaIntervalo(horaInicio, horaFinal) {
    let fechaInicio = horaFija(horaInicio),
        fechaFinal = horaFija(horaFinal)

    if (fechaFinal < fechaInicio) {
        fechaFinal.setDate(fechaFinal.getDate() + 1)
    }

    const diferencia = fechaFinal - fechaInicio,
        horas = Math.floor(diferencia / 36e5),
        minutos = Math.floor((diferencia % 36e5) / 6e4)
    return [horas, minutos]
} 

inicio.addEventListener('change', e => resultado.value = calculaIntervalo(e.target.value, final.value))
final.addEventListener('change', e => resultado.value = calculaIntervalo(inicio.value, e.target.value))

 </script> 

<script>
    
    
    const
    resultado = document.getElementById('resultado'),
    finaln = document.getElementById('finaln'),
    resultadon = document.getElementById('resultadon');

function horaFijan(horan) {
    const dian = new Date()
    dian.setHours(...horan.split(','), 0)
    return dian
}

function calculaIntervalon(horaInicion, horaFinaln) {
    let fechaInicion = horaFijan(horaInicion),
        fechaFinaln = horaFijan(horaFinaln)

    if (fechaFinaln < fechaInicion) {
        fechaFinaln.setDate(fechaFinaln.getDate() + 1)
    }

    const diferencian = fechaFinaln - fechaInicion,
        horasn = Math.floor(diferencian / 36e5),
        minutosn = Math.floor((diferencian % 36e5) / 6e4)
    return [horasn, minutosn]
}

resultado.addEventListener('change', e => resultadon.value = calculaIntervalon(e.target.value, resultado.value))
finaln.addEventListener('change', e => resultadon.value = calculaIntervalon(resultado.value, e.target.value))




</script>
```

en la seguda parte separo por la coma

[11](https://%20https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/451956/como-calcular-tiempo-trascurrido-entre-dos-horas-js)
[2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/373651/como-hacer-que-un-input-escuche-la-resta-de-dos-inputs-con-formularios-reactivos)

[3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/514985/sacar-diferencia-de-fechas-con-javascript/515042#515042)
[4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/373651/como-hacer-que-un-input-escuche-la-resta-de-dos-inputs-con-formularios-reactivos)

[5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58688/sumar-o-restar-valores-de-input-din%C3%A1mico-con-javascript)
[6](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20276/suma-de-inputs-con-resultado-autom%C3%A1tico)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esto es lo que buscas, agregué una validación para que el número de horas trabajadas no sea mayor al número de horas de trabajo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function calcularHoras() {
        let horasTrabajadas = document.getElementById("horasTrabajadas").value;
        let horasTrabajo = document.getElementById("horasTrabajo").value;

        // Convertir las horas a minutos
        let minutosActuales =
          parseInt(horasTrabajadas.substr(0, 2)) * 60 +
          parseInt(horasTrabajadas.substr(3, 2));
        let minutosTotales =
          parseInt(horasTrabajo.substr(0, 2)) * 60 +
          parseInt(horasTrabajo.substr(3, 2));

        // Verificar que las horas trabajadas no sean mayores a las horas de trabajo
        if (minutosActuales > minutosTotales) {
          document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML =
            "Error: Las horas trabajadas no pueden ser mayores a las horas de trabajo.";
          return;
        }

        // Calcular la diferencia en minutos
        let diferenciaMinutos = minutosTotales - minutosActuales;

        // Convertir los minutos a horas y minutos
        let horas = Math.floor(diferenciaMinutos / 60);
        let minutos = diferenciaMinutos % 60;

        // Mostrar el resultado
        let horasFormato = formatTime(horas, minutos);
        document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML =
          "Tiempo restante: " + horasFormato;
      }

      function formatTime(horas, minutos) {
        let horaString = horas.toString().padStart(2, "0");
        let minutosString = minutos.toString().padStart(2, "0");
        return horaString + ":" + minutosString;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Introduce las horas trabajadas y la horas de trabajo para calcular las
      horas que quedan por trabajar:
    </p>
    <label for="horasTrabajadas">Horas trabajadas:</label>
    <input type="time" id="horasTrabajadas" /><br />
    <label for="horasTrabajo">Horas de trabajo:</label>
    <input type="time" id="horasTrabajo" /><br />
    <button onclick="calcularHoras()">Calcular horas</button>
    <p id="resultado"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no me manda resultado como tal edito mi datos arriba  con el codigo que me dio

Comment: no me genera numero correcto

Comment: Modifique el código, creo que el problema esta en calculaIntervalon.

Comment: no me  genera los datos

Comment: Ya edite el código de nuevo.

Comment: no tengo problemas con calcular la hora

Comment: Entonces quieres que te guarde el resultado como un número en lugar de hora y fecha?

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

`Number` para string a numero ya sea float o int

`replace` remplaza un string por otro

```js
test = Number("13,40".replace(",","."))-Number("3".replace(",","."));
console.log(test)
```

usando varirables

```js
// se usan string porque es lo que devuelve
// document.getElementById()
n1 = "13,40";
n2 = "3";
n1 = Number(n1.replace(",","."));
n2 = Number(n2.replace(",","."));

/// restamos
console.log(n1-n2)
```

Comment: despues como lo restaria del otro numero

Comment: hay esto restando puede pasarlo a variables separadas si se te hace mas fasil, corrijo

Comment: lo estaba haciedo haci pero no me genera el numero en mis variales

Comment: edito la parte de arriba de mi preguta